# Custom featured products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

We use Uncode as a theme and would like to fix the shop/product archive and how each product is displayed. What file would we use to make these changes?

For example, we would like to move the product title into the same div as the product image. Thankful for all the help!